# Passing by reference in Xcode, C language

Tags: c, xcode

I'm implementing stack in C and I define pop function in C file:

```
int pop(int &x, int &y);
```

Xcode shows error (pointing on the first argument): Expected ')'
Any ideas why I have that problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't have "pass by reference" like C++. To implement something like this, [you need to use pointers](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/):

```
int pop(int *x, int *y);
```

...and somewhere else, in a function...

```
int a, b;
int c = pop(&a, &b);
```

(It's hard to know exactly what syntax details to give without knowing more about what the arguments are meant to be.)

Answer (score 2):

C does not have references. C++ has.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't use pure C for ages.